# LinQ expression using many-to-many tables in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework

I have 3 tables, Movie, Actor and MovieActor. When i click on an actor i want all the movies from that actor to be shown but im not able to accesss the MovieActor.ActorID.

this is what i have so far:

```
actor = (Actor)listBoxSearchResult.SelectedItem;
var result = db.Movies.Where(a => a.MovieActor.ActorID == actor.ActorID).ToArray();
```

Suggestions?

EDIT: Allright, the answer was easier then i thought, it is:

```
var result = actor.Movies.ToArray();
```

Comment: "but im not able to accesss" -> not clear. Could you show the code of your entities?

Comment: I just mean that it doesnt show up in the intellisense/smarttag 

Error 1 'MovieCollection.Movie' does not contain a definition for 'MovieActor' and no extension method 'MovieActor' accepting a first argument of type 'MovieCollection.Movie' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: OK for the meaning, now it would be useful to provide the code generated by you (code first) or by EF (DB/Model first) for your entities.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wMUwAT8T <-- here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

var result = actor.Movies.ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

Might be something like:

```
var result = from m in db.Movies
             join ma in db.MoviesActor
             on m.MovieId equal ma.MovieId
             joins a in db.Actor
             on ma.ActorId equals a.ActorId
             Where a.ActorId = actor.ActorId
             select m;

result.ToArray()
```

Comment: it complains abou db.MovieActor (yes i correct to MovieActor instead of MoviesActor)

Answer (score 1):

Let's

```
    List<int> MovieIdList=db.MovieActors.Where(t=>t.ActorID==actor.ActorID).Select(t=>t.MovieID).ToList();
var result=db.Movies.Where(a => MovieIdList.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
```

its may be solve your problem...
Note : a.Id reprsent movie Id of your table

Comment: same error as before. Cant access it with intellisense and the code doesnt compile.

Comment: can you describe ur table stracture.....for further proccessing because i am getting rsult with above query ...   it may be possible that ur table stracture may be diff from my table stracture which i hv use for solution